# Getting core_3.sfdc.isInternalUrl is not a function when I try to create scratch org in Salesforce from VS code

Tags: community, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Below is the error

Starting SFDX: Create a Default Scratch Org...

04:42:18.799 sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias trailhead --durationdays 7 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
04:42:24.219 sfdx force:org:create -f config\project-scratch-def.json --setalias trailhead --durationdays 7 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
ended with exit code 1

**core_3.sfdc.isInternalUrl is not a funct**ion

Answer (score 0):

if you have the salesforcedx plugin installed, don't.

More information from the announcement here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1016

Comment: Yes after uninstalling the salesforcedx plugin it's working properly. thanks